# Problem When Compiling with Slackbuild Script

Tags: networking, ssl, slackware

I have done a full install of slackware 15.0.  Previously, I had no problem compiling & installing software using `sboui` or directly from the Slackbuild script.  Lately I have been getting errors.  If I try upgrading `gtest` with `sboui`, I get the following:

```
gtest is already installed.
Installed package: gtest-1.10.0-x86_64-4_SBo
Available version: 1.14.0
--2024-02-04 14:24:12--  https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/v1.14.0/googletest-1.14.0.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 140.82.113.4
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|140.82.113.4|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert TLS Hybrid ECC SHA384 2020 CA1,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
There was an error downloading the source file.
md5sum: googletest-1.14.0.tar.gz: No such file or directory
Error: md5sum check failed on googletest-1.14.0.tar.gz. Continue anyway? (y/n):
```

If I try downloading the source & slackbuild tar builds and try running the .Slackbuild script directly, I get:

```
[ 12%] Building CXX object googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
In file included from /usr/include/errno.h:28,
from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/cerrno:42,
from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:6607,
from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/string:55,
from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/ios_base.h:41,
from /usr/include/c++/11.2.0/iomanip:40,
from /tmp/SBo/googletest-1.14.0/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:54,
from /tmp/SBo/googletest-1.14.0/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:38:
/usr/include/bits/errno.h:26:11: fatal error: linux/errno.h: No such file or directory
26 | # include <linux/errno.h>
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any ideas on how to fix these problems.

**UPDATE:**

```
$ update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

Still get the same error message.  And, the headers are installed.
In fact, I see several erron.h files in various subdirecitories.

```
$ ls /var/log/packages/kernel-headers-5.15.117-x86-1  
/var/log/packages/kernel-headers-5.15.117-x86-1  
$ pwd  
/usr/src/linux  
$ find . -name errno.h  
./arch/powerpc/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./arch/sparc/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./arch/parisc/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./arch/mips/include/asm/errno.h  
./arch/mips/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./arch/alpha/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./tools/arch/powerpc/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./tools/arch/sparc/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./tools/arch/parisc/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./tools/arch/x86/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./tools/arch/mips/include/asm/errno.h  
./tools/arch/mips/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./tools/arch/alpha/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./tools/bootconfig/include/linux/errno.h  
./tools/include/uapi/asm/errno.h  
./tools/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h  
./include/linux/errno.h  
./include/uapi/linux/errno.h  
./include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h
```

Answer (score 1):

The first in your post is `Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority` which would require an up to date certificate bundle to resolve.  Does the command `update-ca-certificates` do anything?

The second problem in your post is `fatal error: linux/errno.h: No such file or directory` which usually indicates your machine does not have the `kernel-headers` installed.

Comment: ```# update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.```   ```sboui``` still giving the same error message.

Comment: kernel headers are installed.  if I do a ```find /usr/src/linux/ -name errno.h```, I see several errno.h files.

Comment: If `update-ca-certificates` does not fix the error, then it would seem you do not have a certificate bundle that can verify Github's certificate.  What version of `ca-certificates` is currently installed?  As for the kernel-headers, does the installed version of `./include/linux/errno.h ` match the running kernel?  Otherwise, I have no idea where `slackbuild` is looking for those includes.

Comment: ```ca-certificates-20240203-noarch-1_slack15.0```  ```uname -r``` shows 5/15/118``` which is where /usr/src/linux is linked to.  Is there a way to see exactly what file erron.h file is looking for?